# Forbidden 403 error using HttpWebRequest

Tags: wcf, httpwebrequest, iis-8

I've managed to solve the issue, but I want help understanding it because I don't like the solution.

I have a WCF service that makes a HttpWebRequest to a Azure REST API service. However when this line of code is called

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

A 403 Forbidden error is returned. The content length is 0 and both the error code and description say "Forbidden".

Now if I copy my code into a console application it works fine. So this lead me to believe that it came down to permissions within the Application Pool Identity.

Sure enough if I change the identity of the application pool to myself, my code starts to work.

My question is how can I grant permissions to the built-in **ApplicationPoolIdentity** account so I can execute an HttpWebRequest?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most probably due to user settings not being available to the **ApplicationPoolIdentity** user.

I have tested a WCF method that creates a WebRequest and **works both** when the service is **self-hosted** as a **console** application AND when it is **hosted under IIS** using the **ApplicationPoolIdentity**

I have tested it on a Windows 7 machine.

One possible setting that could cause the problem may be the **HTTP proxy**, commonly used in corporate environments.

If there is a proxy setting for your logged-in user you could try to:

1.Set the Proxy property of the WebRequest programmatically.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.proxy.aspx) for documentation.

OR

2.
Set the proxy to be used by setting the defaultProxy element in the Web.config

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx) for documentation.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll give this a try and see what happens.